# Search / replace in bash script with dynamic part

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I'm writing a bash script and I want to edit a PHP config file, find a string and replace by another.

The hard part is that I want this search/replace to be dynamic.
Here is an example:

```
define('APP_VERSION', '1.0.31');
```

The goal is to replace 1.0.31 by another version number.

How could I achieve that? I've tried with sed, but can't isolate the version number part (because it's not always the same, so I can't directly search for 1.0.31)

Thanks

Comment: When you say `replace 1.0.31 by another version number` - do you know the new version number in advance or do you need to calculate it based on whatever version number you find in the file (e.g. add 1 to it)?

Comment: Please clarify whether or not the line beginning with `define('APP_VERSION', ` the only such line in the whole PHP config file.

Answer (score 3):

The point of regexes is to match non-static text. To replace any version number with `123` use

```
sed "s/define('APP_VERSION', *'[^']*')/define('APP_VERSION', '123')/"
```